# Azure instance provisioning using ansible - Error checking for existence of name gibson - 401

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, azure, ansible

I'm trying to provisioning Azure instance by using **ansible 2.3**

While trying to provisioning I got the error,

Error checking for existence of name instance_name - 401 Client Error:

Unauthorized for url:
'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/********/resourcegroups/gibson?api-version=2016-02-01

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. By passing *tenant* to **UserPassCredentials**

In **azure_rm_common.py** file, inside ansible/module_utils applied the patch like below,

line no **188**,

**self.azure_credentials = UserPassCredentials(self.credentials['ad_user'], self.credentials['password'])**

change the above line like

**self.azure_credentials = UserPassCredentials(self.credentials['ad_user'], self.credentials['password'],                                                     tenant=self.credentials['tenant'])**

Then it's working fine